# Sending Email in .Net Core without using a class library

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

.Net Core (as of now) lacks the `System.Net.Mail` namespace and the preview version of this namespace which is available through nugget lacks `SmtpClient` which is the most important type of it. However, if one does not like to use class libraries for some reasons (such as to be an independent hero), is there any way to send an email using the available tools in .Net Core (HttpWebRequest, HttpClient, Sockets, etc.)? If so how could this be done (**example and not theory**).

Comment: Not without writing your own library - if you're more concerned with just having the code to read/modify yourself than writing it all yourself, why dont you have a read through the code for MailKit (https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) and then decide whether or not you want to tackle that beast. Good luck :)

Comment: @Arrrr Your option is to use a TCP library to write your own smtp class. There is nothing, other than examples from other libraries, that we can provide to help you with that. Email is not HTTP so using Http libraries is not even in the right ballpark

Comment: @JoePhillips: It can be simply done using socket programing. Check my answer.

Comment: @Transcendent I know because that's what I already said in my comment

Comment: @JoePhillips: I removed my answer because I didn't realized in the very beginning that it can simply be misused for scamming and hacking.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely could write your own library to send emails. The question is "Should you?" The amount of time required would not be a worthwhile endeavor unless you fully intended to make the library available to a broad audience.

The original `SMTP Specification (RFC 821)` (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) was about 68 pages. Implementing this specification was "doable" but required significant effort. The newer `SMTP Specification (RFC2821)` (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821) is 79 pages.

Beyond the implementation of the functionality specified in RFC 2821, you also need to be familiar with a number of other RFCs and documents. (A brief look through the references listed from pages 68 to 70 will certainly give you a bit of pause.)

The best options for anyone sending Mail with `.NET Core` would be to either use a service such as SendGrid (http://sendgrid.com/) or a free and open source library like MailKit (https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). I believe that most `.NET Core` deployed sites are using one of these two methods for sending emails.

Steve Gordon did a really nice blog post (https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/how-to-send-emails-in-asp-net-core-1-0) on using the MailKit library with ASP.NET Core.

Even if you wanted to build your own `SMTP librar`y (and I am definitely not advocating that), the best approach might be to fork something like `MailKit` (https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) via `GitHub` and then modify it. That would at least allow you to play with and iteratively modify a working implementation.

Most of your work would be done using components from the `System.Net.Sockets` namespace. Here is the reference for `.NET Framework 4.7` version (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets?view=netframework-4.7). It should be fairly similar to the `.NET Core` implementation although I have not tested it.

Sometimes the best advice is "Just because you can doesn't mean you should." Please don't be an "independent hero." Go with what works.